# Using the Comparable Object with min/max heaps

Tags: java, data-structures, heap

First of all this is a homework question

I understand how to pop and push onto a heap, i understand how to do it with integers.
My homework asks to write:

A pop that returns a Comparable Object

And to push(comparable item) onto a heap.

I need help in understanding what im supposed to do with this comparable object or what it represents . Thank you!

Comment: Have you started by reading `Comparator` javadoc?

Comment: Or show us some of your integer code, and we can work off of that.

Comment: I understand the PushUp method and reHeaping of Push and Pop. But what does it mean when it returns a Comparable Object? Or uses a Comparable object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Comparable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) objects have a method [`compareTo`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo%28T%29), which as described in the JavaDoc:

> Compares this object with the specified object for order. Returns a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as this object is less than, equal to, or greater than the specified object.

For example, take: (`Integer` is just an example of a `Comparable` object)

```
Integer a = new Integer(10);
Integer b = new Integer(20);
Integer c = new Integer(10);
```

The following are true:

```
a.compareTo(b) < 0
b.compareTo(a) > 0
a.compareTo(c) == 0
```

This is not unlike accepting `int`s:

```
int x = 10;
int y = 20;
int z = 10;
```

With similar comparable relationships that are true:

```
x < y
y > x
x == z
```

Comment: So Integer is a Comparable Object? So the method Push(Comparable item) can be called with a integer as a parameter?  Say Push(5)?

Comment: @Dahnny012: It's just one example of a `Comparable` object, I've updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: My homework is asking me to make a heap with those methods. And then make a subclass min-heap and subclass max-heap. They inherit Push and Pop but wouldnt that not work since they push and pop with different comparisons. Should heap's push and pop use a compareTo method and then should i just override that compareTo method in each subclass?

Comment: @Dahnny012 I'm trying to provide you the information you need to be able to work through your homework, not actually solve your homework problem (it's more effective for you to do that). I would assume that a min or max heap will require comparing two objects to understand their ordering, and my explanation above walks you through how to work out the order of two elements.

Comment: I can  implement a min and max heap but i dont see the point of making it a subclass of heap. Is what im asking sorry. Since their comparators in push and pop are different.

Comment: @Dahnny012 It seems reasonable that you would make a general heap which does not specify any kind of ordering, and then make more specific variations that specify an ordering, such as min-order or max-order.